# Why update Object with HQL does not work in Java application?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to update a property of an object. I update this object through HQL query like this:

```
update Product set availableCount =(availableCount + :avCount), purchaseCount=(purchaseCount + :pCount) where id=:pId
```

but the changes are not apply in object(Product). but I'm trying this by Hiberant Update() method every thig is Okay and final result has been applied in correct way!

what is the reason of this problem about using Hql for Update?!

Answer (score 0):

Read what the [JPA specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a5636) says about this, which is

> The persistence context is not synchronized with the result of the bulk update or delete.

> Caution should be used when executing bulk update or delete operations because they may result in inconsistencies between the database and the entities in the active persistence context. In general, bulk update and delete operations should only be performed within a transaction in a new persistence context or before fetching or accessing entities whose state might be affected by such operations.